# Send a one way message in a group

Tags: signalr

I need to be able to have a chat where inside a group, there will be two members, and one will be able to send a message to the other, in one direction only.

I'm trying

```
Clients.Group(group).User(user)
```

But `Group` does not have a `User` method

Answer (score 0):

It helps to browse through class members...

```
 Clients.OthersInGroup(group)
```